# MongoDB return all documents by field without duplicates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there any way in the mongo shell I can return all documents in a collection, but order them by a specific field and remove any documents with fields the same as other documents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sort I would use [sort](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order).
To remove document with same value: [distict](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct).

Something like:

```
db.collection.find().sort({field : 1}).distinct('field')
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed to do! Thanks! :)

Comment: I get `Error: sort cannot be used with distinct`

Comment: Now im getting an array of strings instead of an array of objects. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use group in aggregate.

```
db.usersProject.aggregate([


{
   $group:
    {
      _id: { projectId: "$projectId" },
      dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
      count: { $sum:1 }
   }
 },
 {
   $match:
     {
       count: {"$gt": 1}
     }
 }
]);
```

Please follow [this](https://weknowinc.com/blog/how-remove-duplicates-mongodb) article for reference